# Open link in a new tab

Tags: google-chrome, google-search

I am using Google Chrome and when I search Google, I see "Open results in new tab" switched on. I want it to be switched off all the time. If I hover my mouse over it, I see "You can change this default in Search settings". When I click on it, I can disable "Open each selected result in a new browser window". I tried to deselect it, but it doesn't work. If I go to the settings again, there isn't anything changed.

I tried to log out of my Gmail account and then it works, but when I log in again, I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First in chrome, click Manage your google account. Then in Data and Personalization page > inside Activity controls click on Web and App activity and then disable the feature.

HTH